# Creating a confirmation box

Tags: html, css

How can I create a confirmation box that has two choices, "accept" and decline", where accept continues to my website and decline directs the user to their last webpage? I'd also like to have the option for the confirmation to not be shown again for another 30 days (if possible).

Comment: Have you tried anything? We provide help here, but we don't like doing all the work.. Provide us with some code, and tell us your problem.

Comment: I highly recommend bookmarking the following link http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Pinocchio, I'm 15 and don't know how to code. Zero, zilp. I'm taking basic programming courses, but I haven't had the time to try and become a "professional coder" like most of the people on this website. I've tried to modify a basic confirmation code with a redirect code string, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: In no way does my comment imply that you are a noob/professional that shouldn't be asking this question. When asking a question you should provide the code that you have been working with and explain what the issue is. What's so hard about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with javascript:

```
var confirmation = confirm('Do you want to continue on this website?');
if (!confirmation){
    // Redirect the user to his last webpage:
    history.go(-1);
}
```

About the 30 days part, you can do that with cookies (can be done with JavaScript too).